# How I can create button (Java) which will display image. When I onclick button

Tags: java, android

It is code due to him I could make my button to start music, now I want my button to start my music + new image. (Initially image shoulndnt be visible, after clicking buttton it should start display new image and my music)

P.s with music are not problems

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickme);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhKsN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```
       private Button btn;
private ImageView imgDisplay;
private MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clickme);
    imgDisplay=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_display);

    imgDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);   //or use INVISIBLE

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handleMusicState(mp);
        }
    });

    
}

private  void handleMusicState(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
    if  (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
    else mediaPlayer.start();
    ImageDisplay();
}
private void ImageDisplay(){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        imgDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        imgDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but about destination my image where I should write it in my code,  inside handleVisibilityImave(here?) I just used your code, but my app works only in 3-5 seconds and there are not image but music work

Comment: check  my answer again.

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped, but there is some little bag(mistake), when I launch my app the button is located in place where my photo should appear and then when I click button it returns to his initially place(where I set it)

Comment: Althouth I Understood how to fix that thank you))!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your XML add ImageView and set its property to invisible or Gone..

> (**Invisible** will keep the image space in layout & **Gone** will
> remove the image from layout & space will be filled by the next element.)

and in the Java create reference of ImageView & on button tap set its property to visible.

**Example (Without following proper language syntax):**

XML:-

```
<ImageView 
.....imageId
.....width
.....height
/>
```

Java:-

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageId);
image.setVisibility = View.INVISIBLE;

// on button click:
onButtonClick(){
    image.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
}
```

Please use the accurate syntax that language have, here is only the logic is provided.